# Trying to debug program counter / instruction memory module in single-cycle CPU in Verilog

Tags: verilog

Our assignment is to build a rudimentary single-cycle CPU in Verilog, but I'm not getting even more fundamental modules of it correct. For instance, to test the Instruction Memory module, we've been given a text file "hw3Test.txt" with instructions in hex, and I'm trying to slurp that into the IM.

```
00221820
AC010000
8C240000
10210001
00001820
00411822
```

When I run a testbench, I see that the only instructions that get into memory are the second, third, and fourth lines. Here's the IM module:

```
module IM(addr, clk, inst);

   input [31:0] addr;
   input clk;
   output reg [31:0] inst;


   reg [31:0] mem [255:0];
   initial begin
          $readmemh("hw3Test.txt", mem);
   end
   always @( posedge clk) begin
          inst=mem[addr[31:2]];
   end
endmodule
```

And the testbench:

```
module imtest;
    // Inputs
    reg [31:0] addr;
    reg clk;
    // Outputs
    wire [31:0] inst;
    // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
    IM uut (
        .addr(addr), 
        .clk(clk), 
        .inst(inst)
    );
    initial begin
        // Initialize Inputs
        addr = 0;
        clk = 0;
        // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
        #100;
        // Add stimulus here
        clk = 0;
        addr = 0;
        #100;
        forever begin
            #20;
            clk = ~clk;
            addr = addr + 4;
        end 
    end      
endmodule
```

I'm also not sure I'm even getting the PC-to-IM module correct, because aside from the initialized values, everything but the rst and clk signals show no valid values.  Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

```
module pc_im(
    // Inputs
    rst, clk, PCin,

    // Outputs
    inst, PCout
    );

    input clk, rst;
    input [31:0] PCin;
    output reg [31:0] inst;
    output reg [31:0] PCout;

    PC mypc (
        .clk(clk),
        .rst(rst),
        .PCin(PCin),
        .PCout(PCout)
    );

    IM myim(
        .clk(clk),
        .addr(PCout),
        .inst(inst)
    );

endmodule
```

Here's the PC.v module:

```
module PC(rst, clk, PCin, PCout);
    input clk, rst;
    input [31:0] PCin;
    output reg [31:0] PCout;

    always @(posedge clk) begin
        if (rst) PCout <= 0;
        else PCout <= PCin + 4;
    end

endmodule
```

And finally, the testbench:

```
module pcimtest;

    // Inputs
    reg rst;
    reg clk;
    reg [31:0] PCin;

    // Outputs
    wire [31:0] inst;
    wire [31:0] PCout;

    // Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
    pc_im uut (
        .rst(rst), 
        .clk(clk), 
        .PCin(PCin), 
        // Outputs
        .inst(inst), 
        .PCout(PCout)
    );

    initial begin
        // Initialize Inputs
        rst = 1;
        clk = 0;
        PCin = 0;

        // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
        #100;
        rst = 0;

        forever begin
            #100;
            clk <= ~clk;
            PCin <= PCout;
        end

        // Add stimulus here

    end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few things that look suspect.

### Problem 1

It is normally good to use non-blocking assignments in blocks intended to infer registers.

i.e. change

```
always @( posedge clk) begin
      inst=mem[addr[31:2]];
end
```

to

```
always @( posedge clk) begin
      inst<=mem[addr[31:2]];
end
```

### Problem 2

You are changing signals twice per clock cycle, once on negative edge and once on positive edge.

Change:

```
    forever begin
        #20;
        clk = ~clk;
        addr = addr + 4;
    end
```

to

```
    forever begin
        #20;
        clk = 1;
        #20;
        clk = 0;
        addr = addr + 4;
    end
```

### Problem 3

You are using synchronous resets but not supplying a clock during reset.

Consider the code

```
always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (rst) PCout <= 0;
    else PCout <= PCin + 4;
end
```

This block will only activate on positive clock edges.  However, you make reset high while the clock is paused so no reset will happen.

Change

```
    rst = 1;
    clk = 0;
    PCin = 0;

    // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
    #100;
```

to

```
    rst = 1;
    clk = 0;
    PCin = 0;
    #20
    clk = 1;
    #20
    clk = 0;

    // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
    #100;
```